# Pyspark file getting deleted when reading and writing csv to the same location

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading my master CSV file with this line of code

```
master_df = spark.read.format('csv').option("encoding", "cp1252").option("header", True).load(master_csv_path).cache()
```

and then I'm reading some other CSVs file and merging them in master
after that, I'm want to overwrite the master CSV file

```
master_df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("encoding", "cp1252").option("header", True).save(output_path)
```

which I'm doing by this line I'm caching the input df as well
but I'm getting errors

```
java.io.IOException: Concurrent glob execution failed

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Item not found: 'gs://folder/new_master_list/part-00000.csv'. Note, it is possible that the live version is still available but the requested generation is deleted.

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

even my master CSV file is getting deleted from before.

Comment: Yeah, spark will write the folder not a file and this is expected.

Comment: @Praneeth-Kumar Kindly review the answer and mark it as answer/upvote if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Spark does lazy evaluation that means the execution will not start until an action is triggered. In Spark, the picture of lazy evaluation comes when Spark transformations occur. So basically until and unless you perform an action, the spark will not evaluate the results.

Here, although you have used cache() however you need to perform an action such as count() after that so that it actually caches the data before writing back in the same folder otherwise it will first delete the contents of the directory you wish to overwrite and then perform the execution which will give the error of `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Item not found` since you are trying to read data from the same directory.

Therefore, either perform an action such as count() after doing cache() or else use Append as write mode or use another directory to write the data.